# Skip over null arrays in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing

Sorry, I wasn't quite sure how to phrase the question. So I know exactly what the problem is. I am reading from several plists. Some of the plists have no Array stored in "evolved_species_id", which gives the error

> Index out of range

How do I get my code to skip over the instances of "evolved_species_id" that have no stored array? This is the code I'm using to grab the data.

```
convenience init(fromDict dict: [String:Any]) {
    let ef = dict["evolves-from"] as? [[String:Any]]
    let ef1 = ef?[0]["evolved_species_id"]
    self.init(
        prevo: ef1 as? Int ?? 0,
    )

}
```

It never gets to the self.init line because the console error is created at  `let ef1 = ef?[0]["evolved_species_id"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the array exists **and** is not empty

```
convenience init(fromDict dict: [String:Any]) {
    let ef1 : Int
    if let ef = dict["evolves-from"] as? [[String:Any]], !ef.isEmpty {
        ef1 = ef[0]["evolved_species_id"] as! Int
    } else {
        ef1 = 0
    }
    self.init(
        prevo = ef1 // the colon syntax won't compile most likely.
    )
}
```

or use a failable initializer

```
convenience init?(fromDict dict: [String:Any]) {

    guard let ef = dict["evolves-from"] as? [[String:Any]], !ef.isEmpty else {
       return nil
    }

    self.init(
        prevo = ef[0]["evolved_species_id"] as! Int
    )
}
```

Comment: So I read through all of the answers and they essentially say the same thing. The reason I chose this one however, is because it achieves the desired result without wrapping the `self.init` in the `if-let-statement`

Comment: `if - let` is preferable because you can check for multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if let` construct for safely unwrap and check array elements is greater than zero using `where`.

```
if let ef = dict["evolves-from"] as? [[String:Any]] where ef.count > 0 {
let ef1 = ef[0]["evolved_species_id"]
self.init(
    prevo: ef1 as? Int ?? 0,
 )
} else {
 self.init(
    prevo: 0 
)
}
```

and if you're using **Swift 3.0**

```
if let ef = dict["evolves-from"] as? [[String:Any]], ef.count > 0 {
 let ef1 = ef[0]["evolved_species_id"]
  self.init(
    prevo: ef1 as? Int ?? 0,
   )
 } else {
   self.init(
    prevo: 0 
   )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `if let` instead of just `let`. This may avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check whether the array contains anything before indexing it, it will avoid index out of bound exceptions. Since you are trying to get the 0th index element you can re-write your code using `first` property of array:

```
init(fromDict dict: [String:Any])
{
    let ef = dict["evolves-from"] as? [[String:Any]]
    let ef1 = ef?.first?["evolved_species_id"]
    self.init(prevo: ef1 as? Int ?? 0)
}
```

> Use the *first* and *last* properties for safe access to the value of the
>   array’s first and last elements. If the array is empty, these
>   properties are nil.

[Swift Array Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
convenience init(fromDict dict: [String:Any]) {
    let ef = dict["evolves-from"] as? [[String:Any]]
    if !(ef.isEmpty){ /// OR if (ef.count > 0) 
        let ef1 = ef?[0]["evolved_species_id"]
    self.init(
        prevo: ef1 as? Int ?? 0,
    )
  }
 }
```